# ASP.NET C# OData Service + Navigation Property + $expand = null. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I will try to explain my problem as thoroughly as possible with a simplified example. Please note that I am NOT using Entity Framework.

I have this model:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public List<Employment> Employments { get; set; } 
}

public class Employment
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public Guid? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Manager { get; set; }
}
```

I create an in-memory data source:

```
public class MyDataSource
{
    private static MyDataSource instance = null;
    public static MyDataSource Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new MyDataSource();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public List<Person> Persons  { get; set; }
    private MyDataSource()
    {
        this.Persons = new List<Person>();
        this.Persons.AddRange(new List<Person>
        {
            new Person()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"), //Just for simplicity
                GivenName = "John",
                FamilyName = "Doe",
                Employments = new List<Employment>()
                {
                    new Employment()
                    {
                        Role = "Boss"
                    }
                }
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"), //Just for simplicity
                GivenName = "Clark",
                FamilyName = "Kent",
                Employments = new List<Employment>()
                {
                    new Employment()
                    {
                        Role = "Worker",
                        ManagerId = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"), //Just for simplicity
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have this controller:

```
[EnableQuery]
public class PersonsController : ODataController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(MyDataSource.Instance.Persons)
    }
}
```

I configure the EndPoint:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", CreateEdmModel());
        config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count()
    }

    public static IEdmModel CreateEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        var persons = builder.EntitySet<Person>("Persons");
        builder.ComplexType<Employment>().HasOptional(e => e.Manager, (e, p) => e.ManagerId == p.Id);
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Checking the $metadata I see this:

```
<NavigationProperty Name="Manager" Type = "MyNamespace.Person">
    <ReferentialConstraint Property="ManagerId" ReferenceProperty="Id" />
</NavigationProperty
```

Everything looks fine from what I can tell but:

https://example.com/odata/persons?$expand=Employments/Manager

receives everything fine but:

Manager is null for both persons. I was expecting to see John Doe on Clark Kents employment.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it myself.

I realised that it doesn't work like I thought and that I have to add a reference to the manager directly in MyDataSource. After that it works to $expand the manager.

Comment: If you were using an ORM like EntityFramework as your datasource then your initial expectation would have worked, as long as the DbContext could resolve the query. You have effectively defined manual projections, the IQueryable can only query against what you have defined, as such you are correct, you must make sure you define and include the reference to the `Manager` navigation properties.